# the problem of unauthorized in IBM watson assistant Nodejs

Tags: node.js, watson-assistant

I tried the API v1 and v2 of IBM Watson assistant to creat a new conversion.
But it gived me always the samr error code 401 Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials. 
i don't know what happened, thanks in advance for your answers.

```
{ Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
    at RequestWrapper.formatError (E:\Documents\Techniques\Desktop\front_back_end\version-watson\node_modules\ibm-watson\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\requestwrapper.js:218:21)
    at E:\Documents\Techniques\Desktop\front_back_end\version-watson\node_modules\ibm-watson\node_modules\ibm-cloud-sdk-core\lib\requestwrapper.js:206:29
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
  name: 'Unauthorized',
  code: 401,
  message: 'Access is denied due to invalid credentials.',
  body: '{"code":401,"error":"Unauthorized"}',
  headers:
   { 'x-backside-transport': 'FAIL FAIL',
     'content-type': 'application/json',
     'x-dp-transit-id': 'gateway01-1474836587',
     'x-global-transaction-id': '7ecac92c5d14b5ae57e8386b',
     'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000;',
     'x-dp-watson-tran-id': 'gateway01-1474836587',
     'content-length': '37',
     'x-edgeconnect-midmile-rtt': '82',
     'x-edgeconnect-origin-mex-latency': '110',
     date: 'Thu, 27 Jun 2019 12:25:18 GMT',
     connection: 'close' } }
```

const AssistantV1 = require('ibm-watson/assistant/v1');

```
const service = new AssistantV1({
  version: '2019-02-28',
  iam_apikey: '{apikey}',
  url: '{url}'
});

service.message({
  workspace_id: '{workspace_id}',
  input: {'text': 'Hello'}
  })
  .then(res => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
  });
```

I am not sur that for Version2 the session-id is correct or not. But the API v1 doesn't need the session_id, it gives the same error code too.

Comment: Add the command that you used, how you authenticate and format the question.

Comment: Most common reason outside invalid credentials is not supplying the correct `url` endpoint. Defaults to Dallas. You will need to change it if your bot is not there.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty, i am in france now, i had tried many URL from Dallasurl: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api'  to london https://gateway-lon.watsonplatform.net/assistant/api , so i dont know what's the problem.

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty,  I want to comfirm that 'Assistant Settings', 'API details', we can find the information of keys. '{apikey}' is 'Service Credentials--->passeword', and '{workspace_id}' is  'Assistant Details ---> Assistant ID
'. What i confirm is correct, right?